# removing a value from hash if key matches rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have seen many answers as removing any key which has value of `nil` or `""`, But this is not what i want.

I have a hash like this

```
{"firstname"=>"Jie",
 "lastname"=>"Pton",
 "email"=>"jami4@yahoo.com",
 "country_id"=>"1",
 "payment_method"=>"0",
 "insight_id"=>"",
 "password"=>""}
```

And I only want to remove the password attribute from hash if its empty, `NOT ALL` which are empty

Comment: `input.delete('password') if input['password'].empty?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generic solution: for the hash given as an input (I assume it’s `params`, so let’s call it `params`) and the list of fields to be removed when empty:

```
TO_REMOVE_EMPTY = %w|password|
params.delete_if { |k, v| TO_REMOVE_EMPTY.include?(k) && v.empty? }
```

Comment: dynamic constant assignment TO_REMOVE_EMPTY = %w|password| ^ I got this error

Comment: Downcase the name to make it a var.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash.delete('password') if hash['password'].blank?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this solution:

```
hash.reject { |k,v| v.nil? || v.empty? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
hash.reject{|k,v| k == 'password' && (v.nil? || v.empty?)}
```

or if you want to remove `"password"` key from original hash you can use `"!"`

eg. `hash.reject!{|k,v| k == 'password' && (v.nil? || v.empty?)}`